# JQuery Slideshow works in IE/Chrome/Safari but not works in FireFox

Tags: jquery, firefox, slideshow

My page is at http://mureka.byethost32.com/test2.html

You will be aware that in Chrome/IE/Safari, the banner changes every 3 seconds.
However, in Firefox 13.0.1, the banner doesn't changes every 3 seconds.

I also tried Firefox 14.0, still no work.

The jQuery version is 1.7.2

The jQuery tools is 1.2.7

I have no idea where my JavaScript code goes wrong.
Could you provide me any hint?

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code never runs, because your `<script>` tag is:

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="JavaScript">
```

Note the incorrect `type` attribute.  It should be `text/javascript`.